# não consigo conectar com mysql no servidor web

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Está apresentando o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IPservidorweb' (111)' in app/class_universo.php:59
>   Stack trace: #0 app/class_universo.php(59):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=IPservidorweb', 'universo', 'senha') #1
>
> app/load_usuarios.php(15): class_universo->connect() #2
>
> perfil.php(13): include_once('/var/www/html/a...') #3
>
> {main} thrown in app/class_universo.php on line 59

```
  public function connect() {



$dbhost = $this->host;

$dbport = 3306;

$dbname = 'universia';

$dsn = "mysql:host={$dbhost};port={$dbport};dbname={$dbname}";



$this->link = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password); /*linha 59*/

$this->link->exec("set names utf8");

$this->connected = true;
```

}

Comment: E qual é o seu código? O erro aponta uma irregularidade na linha 59 do arquivo `class_universo.php`. Você já verificou o que há nele? Sempre que fizer uma questão, forneça os códigos para que possamos analisar.

Comment: Poste o código e aponte em qual linha se aborda tal erro!

Comment: Celsom, vlw a dica....mue problema é que em local host funciona perfeito. Este erro aparace quando subi a aplicação para o servidor de produção. Acho que é alguma configuração do ubuntu, pois tb não consigo conectar o mysqlworkbench...vou editar o post

Answer (score 0):

vlw pela ajuda...resolvido!!

usei esta link e funcionou perfeitamente:
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Configurando-acesso-remoto-em-servidores-MySQL